# Multiple raw pointers to the same object

Tags: c++, pointers

I have multiple pointers pointing to the same object.

**Each node in the table looks like this:**

```
struct Node
{
    Object * objPtr;
    Node * next;
}
```

**Reading data from the file and storing an object:**

```
Object * currObj;
currObj = new Object(data);
insert(*currObj);
```

**Insert to the table:**

```
void Table::insert(Object & object_)
{
    char key[200];
    object_.getKeys(key);

    char * token;
    token = strtok(key, " ");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        index = calcIndex(token);

        Node * newNode = new Node;
        newNode->objPtr = &object_;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        newNode->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newNode;
        size++;

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

What happens is every object has multiple keys, so I want to add it to the table multiple times(adding pointers). However, I get memory leaks all over the place because I try to access part of memory that has been deleted already. I'm wondering whether by destructors are messed up, or is it insert (I'm not allocating something right)? **strong text**

**UPD**

```
~table()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<capacity; i++)
    {
        Node * head = table[i];
        Node * curr;
        while(head)
        {
            curr = head->next;
            head->next = NULL;
            delete head;
            head = curr;
        }
    }

    delete [] table;
}


~Node()
{
    delete objPtr;
    objPtr = NULL;
    delete next;
    next = NULL;
}

~Object()
{
    if(data)
        delete [] data;
}
```

Comment: I see no delete calls in your code anywhere.  That would be good if you were using a smart pointer.  Use a smart pointer.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: He'd still have non-null copies of the pointer, which now point into freed memory.

Comment: "Perhaps when you delete a pointer, you need to also set it to nullptr." - perhaps not. This practice is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I'll add destructors in a minute

Comment: Off topic: Consider using `std::stringstream` in place of `strtok`. It is an elegant tool for a more civilized age.

Comment: Can you do a [mcve]?

Comment: If you're inserting a pointer into multiple tables, you need to not delete it until all of those go out of scope.  You could write your own reference counting, but that would be a waste of time, just use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Donnie I'm inserting into the same table.

Comment: Little matter, you're still going to free it twice (or more) as you walk the table and free pointers.  use `shard_ptr`

Comment: Same deal. If a pointer has multiple parties each with a say in when the pointer is deleted you either have a serious design flaw or a legitimate case for a `shared_ptr`.  From the information given this sounds like the latter.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I get memory leaks all over the place because I try to access part of memory that has been deleted already.

That is not a memory leak. Memory leaks when you no longer point to memory that was allocated, so you can no longer free it.

What you describe is invalid memory access, which has undefined behaviour.

Without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is impossible to tell where your mistake is, but my crystal ball tells me that you could have avoided it by using a smart pointer.

Comment: Program is a bit too big to post here, so I posted the most relevant parts. I'm just trying to figure out the way to work with multiple pointer pointing to the same object and how to deallocate the memory afterwards. My search yielded no results

Comment: @illia therefore create a [mcve] and post that instead of your big program. You haven't created any objects, so the example clearly isn't complete.

Comment: `currObj = new Object(data)` - doesn't this creates an object?

Comment: @illia OK, you do create an object. But you never destroy it. How could that demonstrate the use of an object after it was destroyed?

Comment: When table destructor is called, Node destructor is getting called, which calls Object destructor, doesn't it?

Comment: @illia sure, but the destructor of a table will not be called unless you have created a table.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't post the whole program here as it is too big to post here. If you want me to show you some other parts of the program - please let me know. I'll definitely do it. I just thought that it would be easier to show where the problem lies

Comment: @illia like I said, you shouldn't post the whole program indeed. Instead create a [mcve] and post that. Something that you can paste into http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ and demonstrates your problem. And don't forget to remove the parts that are not relevant - that means *everything* that does not prevent the reproduction of the problem. I cannot show you where your problem is unless you show a program that has a problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it in a new post?

Comment: @illia no need, you can replace the code in this one.

Comment: Took me a while, if you want to take a look  - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146969/multiple-raw-pointers-to-the-same-object-ft-2)